# Reproduce this figure using matlab for system of ODE's solved numerically

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra, matlab, computational-mathematics

So I believe that I am working with the Becker-Doring equations or the spatially uniform mass-action equations, either way, this was taken from a research paper and I'm trying to reproduce the results using a numerical method of my choice to solve the system of ODE's and then reproduce the figures. I will most likely use Runge-Kutta Method of order 4. Just hoping someone on here has the skills and knows exactly how to reproduce this figure in matlab cause my skills are beginner level.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my code so far, basic

```
function cells
epsilon=0.0001;
M=30;
N=4;
Ns1=20;
Ns2=10;
X=[.0001 .001 .01 .1 1 10 100 1000 10000 100000];
Y=log10(X);
c=zeros(4,1);
m=M;
for t=1:4
    m=m-t*c(t,1);
    t=t+1;
end
for t=1:4
    z=c(t,:)+h*euler(c(t,:),epsilon,m); 
    c=[c z];
    t=t+1;
end
figure(1)
plot(Y,c(1,:),'g');
hold on
plot(Y,c(2,:),'r');
plot(Y,c(3,:),'b');
plot(Y,c(4,:),'k')
hold off
function y=euler(z,epsilon,m)
y(1,1)=-m*z(1,:)-epsilon*z(1,:)+epsilon*z(2,:);
y(2,1)=-m*z(2,:)-epsilon*z(2,:)+m*z(1,:)+epsilon*z(3,:);
y(3,1)=-m*z(3,:)-epsilon*z(3,:)++m*z(2,:)+epsilon*z(4,:);
y(4,1)=-m*z(4,:)-epsilon*z(4,:)+m*z(3,:);
```

[Here is the link to the entire paper](http://www.csun.edu/%7Edorsogna/mwebsite/papers/PRE-5tom.pdf)

Update on code: Overall, I think I'm getting closer to figuring this out. I switched from Euler to Runge-Kutta for my numerical scheme.

```
function cells

%constants
epsilon=0.0001;
M=30;
N=4;
Ns1=20;
Ns2=10;
m=M;%constraint condition

%computing time variable
tstart=10^-4;%Need to implement adaptive time step
tend=10^5;
t=tstart;
h=10^-4;%uniform step size
n=round((tend-tstart)/h);
tspan=[10^-4 10^5];%replace after time step is figured out
logt=log10(tspan);

%Numerical scheme for sigma<1/2
c0=[Ns1,0,0,0,0];%initial conditions
carray=zeros(5,n+1);
carray(:,1)=c0;%adding initial condition to array

for i=2:length(logt)%loop for top graph implemented with Classical RK4
    z=RK4(c,h,epsilon,m); 
    carray(:,i)=z;
    c=z;
    i=i+1;
    t=t+h;
end

figure(1)
tiledlayout(2,1) %initiating display of multiple axes in one figure
nexttile%top plot
plot(logt,carray(2,:),'g')
hold on
plot(logt,carray(3,:),'y')
plot(logt,carray(4,:),'b')
plot(logt,carray(5,:),'k')
hold off

%%Numerical scheme for sigma>1/2
c0=[Ns2,0,0,0,0];
carray=zeros(5,n+1);
carray(:,1)=c0;

for i=2:length(logt)%loop for bottom graph implemented with Classical RK4
    z=RK4(c,h,epsilon,m); 
    carray(:,i)=z;
    c=z;
    i=i+1;
    t=t+h;
end

nexttile%bottom plot
plot(logt,carray(2,:),'g');
hold on
plot(logt,carray(3,:),'y');
plot(logt,carray(4,:),'b');
plot(logt,carray(5,:),'k');
hold off

%Classical RK4
function W4=RK4(c,h,epsilon,m) 
X1=c;
X2=c+h*(1/2)*rhs(X1,epsilon,m);
X3=c+h*(1/2)*rhs(X2,epsilon,m);
X4=c+h*rhs(X3,epsilon,m);
W4=c+h*((1/6)*rhs(X1,epsilon,m)+(1/3)*rhs(X2,epsilon,m)+(1/3)*rhs(X3,epsilon,m)+(1/6)*rhs(X4,epsilon,m));

%System of ODE's
function dcdt=rhs(c,epsilon,m)
dcdt(1)=-m*c(1)+epsilon*c(2);
dcdt(2)=-m*c(2)-epsilon*c(2)+m*c(1)+epsilon*c(3);
dcdt(3)=-m*c(3)-epsilon*c(3)+m*c(2)+epsilon*c(4);
dcdt(4)=-m*c(4)-epsilon*c(4)+m*c(3)+epsilon*c(5);
dcdt(5)=-epsilon*c(5)+m*c(4);
```

Comment: If more info is required or better picture let me know and I will update

Comment: This is a programming question. Better to consult Stack Overflow.

Comment: Indeed use Runge Kutta. It is the method of choice. Euler is not. Could you give a photography including the legend in order that I can have an idea of the values of the parameter (I could attempt to write the Matlab program).

Comment: Sure thing, give me a sec

Comment: The standard in Matlab is not RK4, it is ode45 for the 5th order Dormand-Prince explicit RK method (with embedded 4th order for error sensing, adaptive step size) or ode15, ode113 for a variable order linear multistep method (one of them is implicit, so better suited for stiff problems, which this one is apparently not.)

Comment: It would be better if you wrote out the formulas of the system as text, and would also extract the relevant set of parameters, only use images for the plots. What I did not find in the images is the kind of time dependence in $m(t)$, in your code you seem to indicate that it is also computed from the state vector $c$?.

Comment: Ok, I'll make a new post containing everything you should need and just post the picture of the graphs. All I'm really looking for is if anyone on here can recreate the graphs similarly to the article and tell me how.

Comment: The graphs need not be based on this data set

Comment: @LutzLehmann I think you are right, right below the graph in the legend it states that there is a constraint condition on m(t) and c_0(t). I looked at another similar graph in the paper and they stated that they used m(t)=M.  So I'm going with this and removing the for loop for m(t). I would like to ask the author what he/she meant by constraint condition. It could be key to figuring this out.

Comment: I think I almost got it, just gotta figure out how to implement the time step and I'm set. The trouble I'm having is that it might require an adaptive time step since a uniform step size might be out of the question since the interval increases on a logarithmic scale. Any ideas? I'll update my code

Comment: Does anyone know if it's possible to find out the time step that an ODE solver uses? I was shown that ODE15 can solve this but I'm not allowed to use it.

Comment: @LutzLehmann would you be kind enough to look at my second post regarding same figure but dealing with the step size .

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4326239/finding-appropriate-step-size-for-ode-system-numerically-solved-without-ode-solv